# Parameter read when Task runs, not when declared

Tags: c#-4.0, task

I'm trying to find out how to do this properly. What's happening is in "Task MyTask = new Task(() => Match.UserObject.InitUser(tmpUserObject));", **tmpUserObject** is getting evaluated when the task runs and not when it's declared. Since this seems to be a "feature", there must be a proper way to use the value of tmpUserObject at the time the task is declared.

Thanks  :-)

```
Match.UserObject tmpUserObject;    
while (myReader.Read())
{
    if (tmpDict.TryGetValue(UserID, out tmpUserObject))
    {
        tmpUserObject.vchSchoolID.Add(myReader.GetString(5));
    }
    else
    {
        tmpUserObject = new Match.UserObject();
        //Assign some values from reader...
        //Do any processing eg. DoubleMetaphone pre-computation...etc...
    Task MyTask = new Task(() => Match.UserObject.InitUser(tmpUserObject));
    TaskList.Add(MyTask);
    }
}

//Block until all the tasks are done
Task[] MyTaskArray = TaskList.ToArray();
Task.WaitAll(MyTaskArray);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can tell of your code, `tmpUserObject` is a class instance.  It is never "evaluated".  The lambda that you pass to the task ( `() => Match.UserObject.InitUser(tmpUserObject)` ) is evaluated when the task is run, which does happen asynchronously.  That's the purpose of the Task object.

What do you actually mean when you say "use the value of tmpUserObject"?

EDIT: To capture the value, you need to assign it to a new variable with each iteration.  You can do this simply by re-scoping the variable to inside the loop:

```
while (myReader.Read())
{
    // Since we moved this inside the loop, the variable's scope has changed.
    Match.UserObject tmpUserObject;    
    if (tmpDict.TryGetValue(UserID, out tmpUserObject))
    {
        tmpUserObject.vchSchoolID.Add(myReader.GetString(5));
    }
    else
    {
        tmpUserObject = new Match.UserObject();
        //Assign some values from reader...
        //Do any processing eg. DoubleMetaphone pre-computation...etc...
        Task MyTask = new Task(() => Match.UserObject.InitUser(tmpUserObject));
        TaskList.Add(MyTask);
    }
}
```

Comment: The "value" of tmpUserObject is the reference "value" aka memory location. Each time I assign tmpUserObject  to a new object, the reference value changes. I need to "capture" the value of this reference at the time I create the task.

Answer (score 1):

That's called a [closure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_science%29).
It's one of C#'s more powerful features.

If you want to evaluate the expression in advance, you can put it in a separate variable outside the lambda.

Comment: Thanks  :-)  Now I at least have a term I can look up. I have having a hard time googling this question since there are A LOT of results on tasks/lambda/etc

Comment: In case I have a hard time finding an example, since it sounds simple, do you have an example of how to "evaluate the expression in advance"?

Comment: In your case, it's very simple.  Just declare the variable inside the loop so that each lambda (closure instance) gets a separate variable.